# Find the value of a key in an unknown multilevel array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a use defined json string inside a database.

The JSON string has lots of levels. I know my user will define a kay called "basevalue" and place it somewhere in the json.

The problem is, I don't know ahead of time where in the JSON it will be placed, and every use is likely to place is in different places in the array, perhaps at different levels.

This is an example of the JSON data being saved by the user:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "type": "layout",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "section",

      "children": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "row",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "",
              "type": "column",
              "props": {

              },
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "type": "column",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "itemdata",
                  "props": {
                    **"basevalue": "100",**
                  },
                  "children": []
                }             

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm converting this data to an array using json_decode:

```
 $json = json_decode($json, true);
```

No I need to search through the array, and find the key of 'basevalue' and then get whatever value the user has input, in the case above that would be '100'.

So to the issue is, I have no idea what 'node' the 'basevalue' key will be. It could be 40 deep, it could be in the first 'children' node.

This is up to the user.

So how do I take any version of the JSON string about and return the '100'?

Many thanks.

Comment: [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/array-walk-recursive) until your callback gets the key you want.

Comment: without decode: `$chunk1 = explode("\"basevalue\":", $json);
$chunk2 = explode(",",$chunk1[1]);
$chunk3 = trim($chunk2[0], '" .');
echo $chunk3;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively iterate over the data and get the value of the key `basevalue`. To make this search faster, we can adopt an early exit approach **similar to** [`breadth first search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). By this, we call add all values who are arrays in a queue and continue our search for the key `basevalue` and later on deal with pending queue. This would be faster than basic recursion because a lot of times it's possible that key was on the same level but we searched all the way down on all other trees which proved out to be trivial.

**Snippet:**

```
function getBaseValue($arr,$search_key){
    $pending_calls = [];
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $pending_calls[] = $value; // queue them for later judgement
        }else if($search_key === $key){
            return $value;
        }
    }

    foreach($pending_calls as $call){
        $returned_val = getBaseValue($call,$search_key);
        if($returned_val !== false) return $returned_val;
    }

    return false;
}


echo getBaseValue($arr,'basevalue');
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/gdLK1